# CSS: How to number div containers?

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/rcomvpm5/

As you can see in this sample, the used approach works on unordered list, what it does is that it adds numbers for every `li` item.

Why the same method does not work on `div`?. I'm open for javascript approach.

```css
ul.menu,
div.container { 
  counter-reset: item;
  list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
ul.menu li::before,
div.container::before {
 content: counter(item) " ";
 counter-increment: item;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>

<div class="container">
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rcomvpm5/1/ it must be `div.container div::before`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target the children `div.container div::before` elements for your counter elements, not the parent container.

```css
ul.menu,
div.container { 
  counter-reset: item;
  list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
ul.menu li::before,
div.container div::before {
 content: counter(item) " ";
 counter-increment: item;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>

<div class="container">
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is adding the counter before the .container div, not each of it's child divs. Try this:

```
ul.menu li::before,
div.container div::before {
    content: counter(item) " ";
    counter-increment: item;
}
```